Laravel filament code question to get and pass value from custom form
I am pretty much new to use Laravel/Filament. I buil up the simple CMS for my business using Filament and I can't find any soultion to get values (site name and date) to be passed to new tap window.
I created the custom filament page, which is called as Report Generator. It can bring up the select option from databasement and select the date. After then, I can't pass two values (site and date) to new window tap. I searched throught stack overflow and found some code but not sure how I deliver these two value.
I route value to inspection.blade.php..
If anyone could help me, I will very appreciate for your help.
//custom page with form
use Filament\Pages\Page;
class Report extends Page implements HasForms
{
use Forms\Concerns\InteractsWithForms;

protected static ?string $navigationIcon = 'heroicon-o-document-text';

protected static string $view = 'filament.pages.report';

protected static ?string $navigationLabel = 'Report Generator';

protected static ?string $title = 'Report Generator';

public $site;
Public $date;

public function mount(){

    $this->form->fill();
}

protected function getFormSchema(): array
{
    return [
        Section::make('Inspection Report')
            ->columns(2)
            ->schema([
                Select::make('site')
                    ->label('Select Site Name')
                    ->required()
                    ->searchable()
                    ->options(Site::all()->pluck('name', 'name')),

                DatePicker::make('date'),

            ]),

  
        
    ];
}

public function submit() :View
{`your text`
  
    dd($this);
   
}



//report.blade.php 

<x-filament-panels::page> <x-filament::card>

{{ $this->form }}

<x-filament::button wire:click="submit" id="cardButton" type="button" class="float-right"> {{ __('Submit') }}

</x-filament::button>

</x-filament::card> </x-filament-panels::page>

}

